# Can STL or Boost help sort a map by value?

Tags: c++, sorting, boost, stl, stdmap

The word "sorting" in the title may be misleading here. I'm looking for this behaviour:

```
{ 1: 100,               { 1: 1,
  3: 10,        =>        3: 10,
  5: 1000,                5: 100,
  9: 1 }                  9: 1000 }
```

That is, reassign the values to existing keys in ascending order.

This would not be hard to do with a temporary:

```
using K = int;
using V = int;
std::map<K, V> myMap{ {1, 100}, {3, 10}, {5, 1000}, {9, 1} };
std::vector<V> tempVec; // insert map values into vector
std::transform(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), std::back_inserter(tempVec),
               [](auto const& mapPair) { return mapPair.second; });
std::sort(tempVec.begin(), tempVec.end());
size_t i = 0;
for (auto& mapPair : myMap) {
    mapPair.second = tempVec[i++];
}
```

Can this be simplified or even better, be done in place?

Comment: Technically, if either key or value is user-defined type, you could overloads std::swap for `value_type` of the map (you are allowed to add overloads in std:: namespace if they depend on used-defined type) to swap only value part and then use std::sort with custom comparator. In practice, it would not be a good idea.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot The downside is that it would be hard to get rid of the custom overload in contexts where the default behaviour is desired, right?

Comment: Yes. However, as `value_type` for map is `pair<const key, value>` for which default behavior is _compile error_, I do not think _this_ is the problem. People looking at `std::sort` over a `std::map` and trying to figure out, what sorcery is this, are a problem, though.

Comment: Feels like an XY problem. If the key doesn't have to go with the value, why use a map? Seems like you want two sorted vectors of equal size, or two sets or something else.

Comment: @RyanP The map is used as a PHP-like associative array in a scripting language I implemented, random access might be important for many use cases.

Comment: `myMap[mapPair.first] = tempVec[i++]` should be `mapPair.second = tempVec[i++]`.

Comment: `map::iterator` does respect random iterator concept (even in taking account only values and ignoring the const key part).

Comment: Do you need an efficient algorithm? Or O(n^2) will be ok?

Comment: @DAle that is totally ok.

Answer (score 1):

If we don't need an efficient algorithm, we can simply implement the selection sort.

```
for (auto mi = myMap.begin(); mi != myMap.end(); ++mi) {
    auto const& mini = min_element(mi, myMap.end(), [](auto const& pa, auto const& pb) { return pa.second < pb.second; });
    swap(mi->second, mini->second);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can't sort a map by value.

Because `std::map` organizes the entries by key in order to do it's job (like `O(log n)` lookup and insertion), there is no way to change this behavior.

What you can do, however, is use a `std::set<YourType>` where `YourType` is a tuple (like `std::pair` or a custom type as shown below) and you provide your custom comparison operator such that the set is organized by value.

```
struct YourType {
  int key;
  int value;
  bool operator<(const YourType& other) const { 
    return std::tie(value, key) < std::tie(other.value, other.key); 
  }
};
```

Comment: OP doesn't really want to _sort a map by value_. They want to _sort the values in a map_, completely breaking the relationship between key and value.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. I don't know who upvoted this.

Comment: You are right. But since the Op already presented a way to do this, I was suggesting to use a different data structure instead.

Comment: @crazypeter This data structure behaves completely differently -- it sorts the pairs, not just the values.

Comment: The wording "reassign the values to existing keys in ascending order" made me think we wanted to preserve the relationship between keys and values. Sorry if the answer wasn't helpful.

Comment: @crazypeter I meant "reassign JUST the values, in sorted order, to the existing keys whose order is preserved"